# What's the meaning of еле-еле?

Tags: значения, сленг

The [Wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5) and the non-existent lingvo entry for **еле-еле** don't shed light on its meaning. I usually misstrust (at least a little), when two words are marked as synonyms. In this case еле-еле must be different from [елe](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ru/Translate/ru-en/%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5). Isn't it?

Comment: Words are duplicated to emphasize their emotional load: 'девушки красивые-красивые', 'небо синее-синее', 'бежать быстро-быстро'. Sometimes the second word in pair receives the prefix 'пре-': 'репка большая-пребольшая', 'небо синее-пресинее'. Duplication is most often met in children's speech, tales, poetry etc. However, 'еле' is most often used duplicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @mr_tron pointed out, the meaning is *very little*, however best English equivalent I can think of is *barely*:

> Он еле-еле дышал.
>   He was barely breathing.
>
> Он еле-еле ехал.
>   He was barely moving.

Depending on the context, some other words of similar meaning can be substituted, all around the same meaning:

> Он еле-еле победил.
>   He barely won. (*This doesn't sound very good.*)
>   He won by a tiny margin. (*This sounds better in English.*)

The meaning of word *еле* is exactly the same, although you could argue that repeating the word twice emphasises its meaning:

> Он еле дышал.
>   Он еле-еле дышал.
>   He was barely breathing. (*Both versions.*)

Comment: Ah! I understood him/her wrong! I thought "Это означает очень мало" was referring to the role of the word in the sentence – that it could be neglected or so. So his/her answer should be "Это означает *очень мало*".

Comment: @c.p. Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Это означает *очень мало*. Обычно относительно скорости или достижения каких-то результатов.

Например:

> Он **еле-еле** ехал - ехал очень медленно.

или

> Он **еле-еле** победил - победил с очень небольшим преимуществом.

Answer (score 2):

It means "by a small margin" or "with little room to spare".

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are cases when one of the usages is considered more appropriate than the other.

An example that comes to mind is "еле слышно" (more correct) vs "еле-еле слышно" (less correct (I think))

Or "он еле-еле двигал ногами" (more correct I think) vs "он еле двигал ногами",

although "еле двигался" seem to be OK